# How to set global variable and

Tags: variables, powershell, if-statement, global-variables

I have this script running every half hour. It sends an email if the value is greater than 99, but I don't want it to send an email every 30 min if value is still 99.

I would only like it to send an email once. if the value goes back less than 99 then again greater than 99 then send an email once only.

Here is the script

```
$main = 100


IF ($main -gt 99) {
 Write-Host $main
 ##Send Email
}
else 
{
 Write-Host "Not Greater than 99." 
}
```

**What I tried, it doesn't work**.
I tried using a global variable and setting equal nothing if `$var1 -eq "NOTSENT" -and $main -gt 99` it will send email and set `$var1 = "SENT"`. I need help here.

```
$main = 100
$var1 

IF (($main -gt 99) -and ($var1 -eq "NOTSENT")) {
 Write-Host $main
 ##Send Email
 $var1 = "SENT"
}
else 
{
 Write-Host "Not Greater than 99." 
 $var1 = "NOTSENT"
}
```

Comment: How is your script scheduled? I guess you have a scheduled task in windows' task scheduler invoking your script every 30 minutes? Then you have to persist your "states" outside the scripts.

Answer (score 2):

"Global" only means it's global to the PS session it was created in.  When the session ends, the variable is gone.  If you need to persist that value from one session to another, you need to write it out to disk, and then read it back the next time the script runs.

Comment: That's what i didn't want to do. I guess I am gonna have to do that.

Comment: It's that or design your script to be constantly running so that the session remains open.@user206168

Comment: I have question, if my script runs. it reads from a text file that an email was sent so it will run else condition. so else condition will set text file to "NOTSENT" so next time script runs it will send email again. can you see what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: Can't tell you how to fix that without knowing how the value is being set.  You need to persist some kind of value history to know if the value has dropped below 99 since the last alert was sent.

Answer (score 2):

mjolinor is correct about the reason it's not working; I won't restate that.

But rather than write to disk, you could set a user level or machine level environment variable instead:

```powershell
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Variable', 'Value' , 'User')
[Environment]::SetEnvironmentVariable('Variable', 'Value' , 'Machine') # requires elevation
```

See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730964.aspx

Comment: That will work, too but won't survive a reboot of the machine running the script.

Comment: Really? I can't reboot my machine right now to test but that doesn't seem right to me. Can you point to some documentation about it?

Comment: @mjolinor Setting either a user level or machine level env var will result in that env var surviving a reboot.  Perhaps you're thinking of Process level env vars which are specific to the process and don't live past the process's lifetime.